# Is it possible to customize the security questions for a password reset?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, password

I'd like to change the security questions for users who need to reset their passwords. Is this possible? I'm using SharePoint 2010.

Comment: You need to expand on what you're asking about. What security questions? What authentication provider? SharePoint has none of this built into it as it doesn't provide AuthN.